# I have just deleted modules.builtin.bin, and now I can not remove any module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I got this error:

`rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/modules.builtin.bin'`

Answer (score 3):

You should run

```
sudo depmod -a
```

to re-create the `modules.builtin.bin` file.

Answer (score 0):

Run depmod. Depmod will need modules.builtin and modules.order for creating other map files. Reboot your linux machine and you should see all modules loaded again.